# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to do a knockout.js project for school and I need to bind an observable array to a select dropdown. The following code does not work and gives this error on the `applyBindings` line:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null

Any ideas? This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <script src="knockout.js"></script>
    <script>
        function ViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.options1 = ko.observableArray([{id: 0, name: "Example option"}]);
        }
        ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- page content -->
    <select data-bind="options: options1"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not call `ko.applyBindings` until you're sure the DOM's loaded. Currently, in your code, you execute `applyBindings` right when that line of code hits. At that point, the `body` tag hasn't even been encountered yet by the browser, so it won't know what to bind to.

A quick fix would be:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <script src="knockout.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select data-bind="options: options1"/>
    <!-- page content -->
    <script>
        function ViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.options1 = ko.observableArray([{id: 0, name: "Example option"}]);
        }
        ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, you could defer said code until the DOM's loaded. If you're also using jQuery in your project you could use the `$(document).ready` idiom for that.